# uniqid() in PHP altered the last string to something else

Tags: php, mysql, qr-code

I'm having a problem with the `uniqid`. I'm trying to save the `uniqid` in the database and create a QR code with it. The last string, as I noticed, was not the same.

Example:
This is the code `622b47895d332` that has been inserted in the database while the filename of the stored QR code is `622b47895d333.png`.

How is it possible that the data in the database doesn't match the filename of the QR code?

Here's the code that I'm currently using in generating a QR code..

```
$text = uniqid();
$path = 'temp/';
$file = $path.uniqid().".png";
$ecc = 'L';
$pixel_Size = 10;
$frame_Size = 5;

QRcode::png($text, $file, $ecc, $pixel_Size, $frame_Size);
```

Here's the full PHP code on how I insert it in the database

```
include 'db_connect.php';

    $conn = OpenCon();

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $text = uniqid();
        $path = 'temp/';
        $file = $path.uniqid().".png";
        $ecc = 'L';
        $pixel_Size = 10;
        $frame_Size = 5;

        // Generates QR Code and Stores it in directory given
        QRcode::png($text, $file, $ecc, $pixel_Size, $frame_Size);

        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $mname = $_POST['mname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $suffix = $_POST['suffix'];
        $dept = $_POST['dept'];
        $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
        $stat = 1;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (qr, fname, mname, lname, suffix, dept, user_type, stat) VALUES ('$text','$fname','$mname','$lname','$suffix','$dept','$user_type','$stat')";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result == TRUE) {

          echo '
          <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible show fade">
          User has been added!
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          ';

        } else {

          echo "Error:". $sql . "<br>". $conn->error;

        }

      $conn->close();

      }
```

Comment: Well, you generate uniqueid twice... of course it will be different..

Comment: `uniqid` returns a new *unique* id every time you call it.

Comment: I'm new with this and I didn't know that. Will surely remember this! It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate `uniqid()` only ONCE, and then reuse it:

```
$uniqueid = uniqid();
$text = $uniqueid;
$path = 'temp/';
$file = $path.$uniqueid.".png";
$ecc = 'L';
```

or as a shorter alternative:

```
$text = uniqid();
$path = 'temp/';
$file = $path.$text.".png";
$ecc = 'L';
```

You wrongly expect to get the same UniqueID from a function which generates/returns "UNIQUE" IDs every time it is called

Comment: I used your solution and it works fine now. I didn't know about that since I'm just new in this. Anyways, thank you so much!

Comment: @cjwrk if this answer solves your issue, make sure to mark it as the Accepted answer. Also for PHP, the documentation is the first place to look at: https://www.php.net/uniqid in this case